# If $a^2 + 1$ is prime then the unitary digit of $a$ must be either of 4,6 or 0 for $\forall a \geq 3 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $a \geq 3$ and suppose $a^2 + 1$ is a prime number. How do I prove the unitary digit of $a$ must be one of $6, 4$ or $0$. I can see it's true for $a^2+1=17, 37, 101, 197, 257...$etc. where the $10^0$ digit of $a$ is $6, 4$ or $0$ and the pattern repeats but how do I show this and formulate it into a proof using modular arithmetic?

Comment: The last digit of $a^2+1$ depends only on the last digit of $a$. So _at worst_ (if you don't come up with something clever) you have ten -- no, seven! -- cases to check.

Comment: Here I'm tacitly replacing the claim with its contrapositive: If $a$ is any number $\ge 3$ that _does not_ end in $4$, $6$, or $0$, then $a^2+1$ is not prime.

Comment: Nice, but what if the question was rephrased as - "If $a^2 + 1$ is a prime number then what are the unitary digits of $a$" here one may try to do this by writing down prime numbers but how to derive that the unitary digits are 4,6,0 when we do not know what the unitary digits will be?

Answer (score 1):

Do it by contrapositive. Suppose the last digits are not $0$, $4$ or $6$. Suppose the last digit be $b$.

1. $b=1\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 2\implies$ Not prime (note that $a\geq 3$ too)
2. $b=2\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 5\implies$ Not prime
3. $b=3\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 2\implies$ Not prime
4. $b=5\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 2\implies$ Not prime
5. $b=7\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 2 \implies$ Not prime
6. $b=8\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 5\implies$ Not prime
7. $b=9\implies (a^2+1)=0 \pmod 2\implies$ Not prime

Hence, $b$ can only be $0, 4 \text{ or } 6.$

Answer (score 0):

If $a=10b+c,0\le c\le9$

$c$ must be even to keep $a^2+1$ odd

If $c=2d$

$a^2+1=(10b+2d)^2+1=100b^2+40bd+4d^2+1$  which is divisible by $5$ if $d\equiv\pm1\pmod5$

So, $c\ne2,8$

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent for primes $p$ and $q$:

- $a^2+1$ is coprime with $pq$
- $a^2+1$ is invertible modulo $pq$
- $a^2+1$ is invertible modulo both $p$ and $q$
- $a^2+1$ is nonzero modulo $p,q$
- $a^2$ is not equal to $-1$ modulo $p,q$

So by the Chinese remainder theorem we get valid values for $a$ by lifting valid values for $a$ modulo primes, i.e., the residue classes such that $a^2\not\equiv -1$.

Now, by the supplement to quadratic reciprocity, the number of solutions $N_p$ to $a^2+1\equiv 0$ modulo $p$
is
$$N_p=\begin{cases}1&p=2\\ 2 & p\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \\ 0 & p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}\end{cases}$$
so by Chinese remainder theorem the number of valid residue classes modulo $pq$ is
$$N=(p-N_p)(q-N_q)$$
which in our case gives $(2-1)(5-2)=3$. You can find the actual residue classes to be excluded by solving $a^2+1\equiv 0$ modulo $2$ and $5$.

- $a^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{2}\Leftrightarrow a\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$
- $a^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}\Leftrightarrow a\equiv 2,3 \pmod{5}$

so the valid residue classes modulo $10$ comprise those that are even and equivalent to $0,1,4$ modulo $5$. That leaves $0$, $4$, and $6$.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2\!+\!1$ odd $\Rightarrow a$  even so $\!\bmod 10\!:\ a\equiv 0,\color{#c00}2,4,6,\color{#c00}8\,$ but $\,a\equiv \color{#c00}{2,8}\Rightarrow\bmod 5\!:\, a^2\!+\!1\equiv (\color{#c00}{\pm 2})^2\!+\!1\equiv 0$